# How to use Redatam (statistics program) with Ubuntu, or recomend alternative

Tags: software-recommendation, migration

I use 12.04 LTS and currently use [Redatam](http://www.eclac.cl/cgi-bin/getprod.asp?xml=/redatam/noticias/software/5/30025/p30025.xml&xsl=/redatam/tpl/p17f.xsl&base=/redatam/tpl/top-bottom.xslt) which is a Windows-only statistics program. It doesn't really work well with Wine, so I'm looking for an alternative.

Can you tell me if there is a similar program for Linux?

Answer (score 3):

[R](http://www.r-project.org/) is probably the most famous and most powerful open source statistics application on Ubuntu. It's free but you will need to learn how to use it. If you're doing this stuff all the time, that probably won't be too hard. If programming doesn't come naturally to you, you might struggle with it.

[Matlab](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/matlab/) has a Linux version and is very popular for statistical analysis. Again, this is a language driven application so there is lots of syntax to learn.

[GNU Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) is free and open source. Less popular than Matlab or R. Language-driven 
again.

[SPSS](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/uk/analytics/spss/) is probably the most commercially used application and is probably the best fit for exactly what you're doing (the others will do what you're asking - but you'll need to program them to do it). SPSS is another HUGE application though so there's going to be a certain amount of learning. They have a Linux version (Debian 6 is the latest they support but this *should* work on Ubuntu too).

Matlab and SPSS have various purchasing options (depending on your organisation) and they vary in different countries anyway, so I'll let you look them up. If you can put the work in, R is every bit as good as them though, and free.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no alternatives to Redatam, you can try running Windows in Virtualbox and installing Redatam there.

But better wait, maybe someone else will find an alternative.